# Handling this website which is redirecting to the same url with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, http-headers

So I'm scrapping this website: https://www.hepsiburada.com/apple-macbook-pro-m1-cip-8gb-256gb-ssd-macos-13-qhd-tasinabilir-bilgisayar-uzay-grisi-myd82tu-a-p-HBV0000130VNO-yorumlari

I'm scraping all the reviews for a particular product on this website. Also handling the pagination. The URL for different pages is like:

https://www.hepsiburada.com/apple-macbook-pro-m1-cip-8gb-256gb-ssd-macos-13-qhd-tasinabilir-bilgisayar-uzay-grisi-myd82tu-a-p-HBV0000130VNO-yorumlari?sayfa=1

https://www.hepsiburada.com/apple-macbook-pro-m1-cip-8gb-256gb-ssd-macos-13-qhd-tasinabilir-bilgisayar-uzay-grisi-myd82tu-a-p-HBV0000130VNO-yorumlari?sayfa=2

https://www.hepsiburada.com/apple-macbook-pro-m1-cip-8gb-256gb-ssd-macos-13-qhd-tasinabilir-bilgisayar-uzay-grisi-myd82tu-a-p-HBV0000130VNO-yorumlari?sayfa=3

The code is working as expected but when accessing the (n/2)+1 page, the website is redirecting to the first page of the comments. That is suppose total pages for a website is 12. Upon accessing the 7th page directly for which the URL is
https://www.hepsiburada.com/apple-macbook-pro-m1-cip-8gb-256gb-ssd-macos-13-qhd-tasinabilir-bilgisayar-uzay-grisi-myd82tu-a-p-HBV0000130VNO-yorumlari?sayfa=7
It redirects to the first page for which the URL is
https://www.hepsiburada.com/apple-macbook-pro-m1-cip-8gb-256gb-ssd-macos-13-qhd-tasinabilir-bilgisayar-uzay-grisi-myd82tu-a-p-HBV0000130VNO-yorumlari

When we goto the 7th page using the website's page links, it opens the 7th page with no issues. But its only when we access the page directly, its redirecting.

How can I handle this with BeautifulSoup? Also, Please don't suggest using Selenium as client needs the task to be done using BeautifulSoup only.

Here's the Python code:

```
from urllib import response
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from django.shortcuts import redirect
import requests
import sys
import re

file_path = 'output.txt'
sys.stdout = open(file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8")

# url = sys.argv[1]
url = 'https://www.hepsiburada.com/apple-macbook-pro-m1-cip-8gb-256gb-ssd-macos-13-qhd-tasinabilir-bilgisayar-uzay-grisi-myd82tu-a-p-HBV0000130VNO-yorumlari'

response = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html5lib')
div = soup.find_all('div', class_='paginationContentHolder')
# l = [(div.contents[0].strip(), span.text.strip())
#     for div in soup.select('div.league-data')
#     for span in div.select('span')] 

divlist = soup.find_all("div", {'itemprop':'review'})
# print(divlist)
# for i in divlist:
#     print(i)
#     print('---------------------------')

pagecount = soup.find('div', {'class':'paginationBarHolder'})
pagelist = pagecount.find_all('ul')
pagelistnew = []
for i in pagelist[0]:
    if i.text.isdigit():
        pagelistnew.append(int(i.text))

maxpage = max(pagelistnew)
print(maxpage)

firstcard = divlist[0]
for i in divlist:
    if i.find('span', {'itemprop':'description'}):
        print('Review: ' + i.find('span', {'itemprop':'description'}).text)
    
    ratinglist = i.find_all('div', {'class':'star', 'style':'width:12px;height:12px'})
    print('Rating: ' + str(len(ratinglist)))
    print('Date: ' + i.find('span', {'itemprop': 'datePublished'}).text)
    
    # rating = 0
    # for j in ratinglist:
    #     rating = rating + 1
    # print(rating)
    
    print()

urlnew = 'https://www.hepsiburada.com/apple-macbook-pro-m1-cip-8gb-256gb-ssd-macos-13-qhd-tasinabilir-bilgisayar-uzay-grisi-myd82tu-a-p-HBV0000130VNO-yorumlari?sayfa='

for i in range(2, maxpage + 1): 
    # payload = {'sayfa':i}
    req = requests.get(urlnew + str(i), headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246", 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}, allow_redirects=False)
    print('URL: ' + urlnew + str(i))
    print(req.status_code)
    print()
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html5lib')
    divlist1 = soup2.find_all("div", {'itemprop':'review'})

    # firstcard1 = divlist1[0]
    for l in divlist1:
        if l.find('span', {'itemprop':'description'}):
            print('Review: ' + l.find('span', {'itemprop':'description'}).text)
        
        ratinglist1 = l.find_all('div', {'class':'star', 'style':'width:12px;height:12px'})
        print('Rating: ' + str(len(ratinglist1)))
        print('Date: ' + l.find('span', {'itemprop': 'datePublished'}).text)
        
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all reviews you can use their API url. For example:

```py
import json
import requests


# HBV0000130VNO is from the URL in the question
url = "https://user-content-gw-hermes.hepsiburada.com/queryapi/v2/ApprovedUserContents?skuList=HBV0000130VNO&from={}&size=10"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0"
}

from_ = 0
while True:
    data = requests.get(url.format(from_), headers=headers).json()

    # uncomment to see all data:
    # print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

    for d in data["data"]["approvedUserContent"]["approvedUserContentList"]:
        print(d["customer"]["name"], d["customer"]["surname"])
        print(d["review"]["content"])
        print()

    if data["currentItemCount"] != 10:
        break

    from_ += 10
```

Prints:

```
h********** z*********
Mükemmel kalitede bir ürün

A*** T*****
tek kelimeyle EFSANE. Her zaman olduğu gibi Apple kalitesi 1 numara. Benim kullanımımla 2 gün gidiyor şarjı günlük iş maillerimi yanıtlıyor raporlarımı inceliyorum. Akşamda belki bir dizi-film açıp şarjını bitiriyorum. Performansa diyecek hiç bir şey yok. Bu mimari ve altyapı son derece muazzam çalışacak şekilde tasarlanmış zaten.

E*** D*******
Kesinlikle fiyatıyla performansının birbirini fazlasıyla karşıladığı şahane bir iş istasyonu. Malzeme yapısı ve içindeki yeni M1 Yonga seti işlemcisi ile uzun süreli kullanımı ve iş gücünü vaat ediyor. Ayrıca içinden çıkan 61W'lık Adaptörü ile hızlı şarj olması ayrı bir güzelliği. Hepsiburada'ya ve Lojistiği olan HepsiJet'e hızlı ve güvenilir oldukları için çok teşekkür ederim.

O**** B****
Mükemmel bir ürün. Kullanmadan önce bu ekosisteme karşı yargıları olanlar, şimdi macbook'uma tapıyorlar.

A**** A*********
2019 macbook airden geçiş yaptığım için söyleyebilirim ki özellikle Apple'ın m1 çip için optimize ettiği safari süper hızlı çalışıyor chrome kullanmayı bıraktım diyebilirim görüntü ses kalitesi çok daha iyi ve işlemci çok hızlı çok memnunum pil 20 saat gidiyormuş ben genelde güç kaynağına bağlı kullanıyorum

Y**** G*****
Ben satın aldığımda MBA 512 GB ve MBP 256 fiyatları birbirine çok yakındı. O yüzden MBP tercih ettim. Arada oyun oynamak isteyenler için MBA yerine kesinlikle tecih edilmesi gereken ürün. Çünkü bazı oyunlarda throttling problemi yaşanabiliyor (Tomb Raider oyunları gibi)

ş***** a****
Tek kelimeyle Apple kalitesiyle tasarlanmış şahane bir ürün; fakat Türkiye şartlarından dolayı sırtımıza ağır yükler bindiren kur farkından kaynaklanan kallavi fiyatı biraz üzüyor.


...and so on.
```